# Listing IDs of polygons within another polygon in the Attribute table

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, overlapping-features, concatenation

I have two polygon shapefiles in QGIS.

I would like to have the polygon `"ID"`s of `'B'` listed in the attribute table of `'A'` for the case that they overlap.

As a demonstration:

[image: intersect of two shapefiles]

I tried combinations of spatial queries, intersects and spatial joins but I won't find an answer. Spatial join only allows statistical summaries of attributes (sum, average, mean).

I also tried using the model builder but didn't find the right arrangement of tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [Virtual layer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html) would work well here:

[image: virtual layer dialog with query]

[image: resulting table]

First hit 'Import' to add your layers then add the query:

```sql
SELECT A.id, group_concat(b.id)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
GROUP BY A.id
```

[`group_concat()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) will concatenate all results into a comma separated string (as your above screenshot). If you want to separate by something other than a comma you can define a custom separator.

If you want to name your columns you can use 'AS ...' for instance:

```sql
SELECT A.id AS a_id, group_concat(b.id) AS b_intersect ...
```

Comment: Thank you. That is, among the current answers, the one that fits to my case best. I work with qgis quite long but didn't know this function.

Comment: @AndyB I'm glad it worked for you! I just recently learned how to use virtual layers myself. Useful when you want some of the advantages of a database without actually implementing one. Remember to accept the answer if it worked for you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Intersect is the right tool. Not sure what happened when you had tested it.

Polygons `'A'` and `'B'` with each attribute, `"A_id"` and `"B_id"`.

[image]

Intersected output `"test_intersect"` and its attribute table (RHS).

[image]

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't fully meet my requirements, because I need the IDs of A to remain unique instead of split-up.

Comment: @AndyB Thanks for your reply. I now understand how intersect alone did not meet your expectation, especially so compared to Jesse's elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that would use the aggregate function in R to get your final data output.

1. Run an intersection of the two layers. This will result in a layer with each and every combination of intersecting polygons.
2. Export the attribute data only and load it in R as a data.frame.
3. Then using the aggregate function to group by the larger polygon ID values (using the c function to concatenate all the smaller polygon IDs to a single row output). 
   E.g., if your data.frame object is called dt then:
   `aggregate(polyIDs1 ~ polyIDs2,  data=dt,  FUN=c)`

[Heres a good description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596515/aggregating-by-unique-identifier-and-concatenating-related-values-into-a-string)