# Divide areas from two vector layers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, vector, area

I'm using QGIS, and I have two vector layers (with polygons),

I'd like to get the % of area of polygon in layer b respect to polygon in layer A, and for that I want to calculate the area of a layer A and the area of a layer B, and then using the vector calculator do (Area B/Area A)*100

1st part (calculate areas) is OK but...
Can I use the field calculator using two different layers (to divide area polygon layer b and area polygon layer A)? I tried but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Which software are you working with? What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking about, providing a screenshot/sample data could help. However, have a look here as these solutions can give you an idea of how to calculate the area/percentage of intersecting polygons from different layers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414975/88814 and
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392861/88814 and
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396887/88814 and
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397101/88814 and